# How to handle a question that will never be answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

This question:

[XSLT filename is printed in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889748/xslt-filename-is-printed-in-output)

attracted a number of comments, the last of which is from the OP saying in effect "I found the problem, and I've fixed it".

There's obviously no point in such a question remaining on the system; but there doesn't seem to be an obvious criterion for closing it. What should one do with it?

Comment: _"After a long search it was a minor typo in the XSL stylesheet"_ => _No longer reproducible_ is the correct close reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the OP said that it was due to a minor typo you can close it with that reason.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.